# События от прозрачного элемента управления

Tags: c#, winforms

Делаю кастомное окно под Winforms. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой- если я делаю игнорирование отрисовки определенных цветов через
`AllowTransparency = true; TransparencyKey = Color.Lime;`
То объекты с данным цветом не генерируют событий (ибо обработчики событий не вызываются). Вопрос, можно ли как- то это обойти?
Прозрачные объекты у меня являются рамкой вокруг окна, чтобы отлавливать курсор мыши в случае, если пользователь хочет изменить размер окна.
Вот скрин из конструктора:
[image: Вид в конструкторе]

Скрин запущенной программы
[image: Скрин запущенной программы]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. В общем, решается это так:
1) Цвет всех границ меняется на `Transparent`
2) Цвет формы меняется на Red (!!!Это важно, с другими цветами не работает!!!)
3) В конструкторе формы прописывается `AllowTransparency = true; TransparencyKey = Color.Red;`
В таком случае границы отрисовываются и генерируют события. Проверено на Win 7, Win 8.1 и Win 10